# Open URL after success in Ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to open an URL from an Ajax function, but the URL is not called.

This is my code:

```
$(document).on( "click",".btndriver", function() {
      var id = $(this).attr("id");
      var nombre = $(this).attr("nombre");

      swal({   
        title: "Select Driver?",   
        text: "Select Driver? : "+nombre+" ?",   
        type: "warning",   
        showCancelButton: true,   
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",   
        confirmButtonText: "GO",   
        closeOnConfirm: true }, 
        function(){   
          var value = {
            id: id
          };
          $.ajax(
          {
            url : "ondemand_driver.php",
            type: "POST",
            data : value,
            success: function() {
              window.location(url); 
            }
          });
        });
    });
```

What is wrong there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't just call an object property key like that. It's not a variable.

Change this

```
 window.location(url)
```

To this

```
window.location = url;
```

Complete Code

```
var url = "ondemand_driver.php";

$.ajax({
    url : url,
    type: "POST",
    data : value,
    success: function() {
        window.location = url; 
    }
});
```

Comment: _not working_ doesn't tell me much. What error are you getting?

Comment: I mean the url is not called, let me see the console.

Comment: Console: windows.location is not a function

Comment: It's supposed to be `window.location`

Comment: Sorry, this is the complete log: Uncaught TypeError: window.location is not a function
    at Object.success (ondemand.js:124)
    at j (jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:2)
    at x (jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:4)

Comment: Ohh I feel stupid now.  `window.location` is not a functtion. It's supposed to be `window.location = url;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to define **url** as variable, the url will be opened only if the ajax request is successful.

Answer (score 0):

Declared the url as variable out of ajax function

```
var url = "ondemand_driver.php";  
$.ajax(
      {
        url : url,
        type: "POST",
        data : value,
        success: function() {
          window.location(url); 
        }
      });
```

its work fine.