# Calling Django view from AJAX function

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, django-2.1

I have a button which passes ID of an object. On pressing of button i want that its corresponding Django view should be displayed.

**views.py**

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
@csrf_exempt
def updateUser(request, id):

    user= get_object_or_404(CustomUser, pk=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UpdateUser(request.POST, instance=user)
        try:
            print("DJANGO VIEW")
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                messages.success(request, ("New user account has been created"))
            else:
                messages.warning(request, ("Data in fields is incorrect, please try again"))
        except Exception as e:
            messages.warning(request, ("Error: {}". format(e)))
    else:
        form = UpdateUser(instance=user)
    context ={'form': form, 'user': user,}
    return render(request, 'user/updateUser.html', context)
```

**urls.py**

```
 path('updateUser/<int:id>/', views.updateUser, name="updateUser"),
```

**my.js**

```
function myfunction($this) {

    var stid = $this;
   console.log("button clicked");
    var request_data = '/user/updateUser/'+stid;
    alert(request_data);
    console.log("data: " + stid);
    $.ajax({
        url:  "../updateUser/" + stid+"/" ,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        processData: true,
        type:  'post',
        dataType:  'html',

        success:  function (data) {
           alert("Success");
           $("#updateUser").html(response);
        },
         error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus + ':' + errorThrown);
         }
    });
}
```

Django view is called but the view is not displayed. Button should render the respective page.

Comment: By "Django view is called", do you mean that you are seeing the "Success" alert? If that is happening but the document is not changing, check your html (which you don't give here) - are you sure there is an element with id `updateUser`?

Comment: I just want to display the page "updateUser/1/".

Comment: I'm a little confused. If you just want the button to go to the new page,then just use a link. Your script will put the new page's content inside an element of the existing page, without reloading the page. What isn't working about this? If it isn't working at all, then have you checked your html as I suggested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything works fine with the code but as highlighted in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46423420/open-url-after-success-in-ajax-function) we just need to give windows.location a variable which is defined out of AJAX. Sweet !